# Is it possible to integrate an external biometric reader with an iOS app?

Tags: ios, ipad, fingerprint, rfid, biometrics

We've developed an iOS app which is installed on an iPad. Users need to look-up customer records to add information to their account. Manual look-up entering the customer name is too slow. To speed up the customer lookup we've started using unique QR codes that are linked to the customers contact ID. The steps are:

1. The app loads up a camera;
2. The customer presents their unique QR code;
3. The app scans the QR code and loads the associated account;
4. User adds information to the customer account and saves.

The app then goes back to step 1 and the steps are repeated. I'm looking for alternative biometric (fingerprint, facial) and RFID options that we could use for these steps.

Has anyone done this with their iOS app?

Do you store the biometric data on the iOS device or do you call a service?

What hardware did you use?

Any info would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried looking for 3rd party hardware suppliers who might have an SDK that can bee added to our iOS app.